# Causes "libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast" an Huge Overhead in Parallel under Version 10.3?

Tags: export, parallelization, rendering

Under Linux (SUSE Linux Enterprise 11) for Mathematica Version 10.2/10.3 I observe the following error in parallel

```
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

for the sub-kernels. This error does not occur for the master-kernel just for the sub-kernels. I also do not observe this kind of failure for Mathematica Version 10.0.

It seems to me that this failure causes an huge overhead in parallel when I execute the following function

```
LaunchKernels[12]

exportFrames[baseName_, a_, ext_:"jpg"] := Module[{l = Length[a], d}, 
 d = Length@IntegerDigits[l];
 ParallelTable[Export[baseName <> IntegerString[i, 10, d] <> "." <> ext,   Style[a[[i]],Magnification->1.5]], {i, l}]
 ]

exportFrames["Exp11krmovie",a1]
```

This function let me render and export several hundreds or thousands graphics in parallel. For instance, under Mathematica Version 10.0 I can render and export a test sample of several hundreds graphics in less than a quarter of an hour. In contrast, under Mathematica 10.2/10.3 I can only generate 1/3 of the sample in an hour.

Inspection by the network tool iftop reveals an one-sided network traffic. Moreover, the tool htop shows me that only the master-kernel is working and the sub-kernels are only showing up sporadical. As a consequence, there is no continuous flow of rendering and exporting the graphic files as under Mathematica 10.0. In average, each 4 minutes it starts to generate a set of 12 graphic files, whereas the whole cycle ends at least after 2 minutes.

Any idea how I can get rid of this error for the sub-kernels?  How can I reset the graphic rendering from a software rendering back to a hardware rendering under Mathematica 10.3?

Comment: I would suggest getting in touch with support with your `SystemInformation[]`. Are you using an NVIDIA video card? Is there any difference if you do `ParallelEvaluate[SetOptions[Developer\`InstallFrontEnd, Developer\`LaunchFlags -> "-mesa"]];` before exporting?

Comment: @ilian Thanks a lot for this great pointer! It works now!! The network traffic is reduced and more balanced now. The whole set of graphics is now generated in a few minutes with an AMD/ATI video card.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this problem recently (Feb 2016) following an update to Raspian's Jessie on the Raspberry Pi.  My solution is probably specific to the RPi, and I apologize in advance if I am considered to have hijacked your question.

I noticed upon starting Mathematica that I would get a similar LibGL swrast driver error.  Following the suggestions mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541343/problems-with-libgl-fbconfigs-swrast-through-each-update) (which is alluded to in the error message you receive) I set the LIBGL_DEBUG environment variable via `export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose` and then re-ran Mathematica, receiving the following verbose message list:

```
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No su
ch file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

For the RPi, the issue was **not** a missing symbolic link as assumed in the solution linked to above.  I therefore suspected a missing package.  Searching for `swrast_dri.so` on https://packages.debian.org/ reveals that this file is in the package `libgl1-mesa-dri` which I installed (`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri`).  Now, running Mathematica (after unsetting the verbose debug variable with `unset LIBGL_DEBUG` resulted in a warning-free start to Mathematica.

As I mentioned earlier, my situation is likely different; however it might be worthwhile to check your packages `dpkg --get-selections | grep libgl1-mesa-dri` and see if installing it also solves your problem.

Comment: I checked the situation on my computer system, and find out that it is neither related to a broken symlink nor to a missing installation of libgl1-mesa-dri. The libgl1-mesa-dri are installed on my computer, but not used anymore after I have changed to proprietary drivers. The proposed workaround works fine on my system, even though the drawback is that I have not to forget to include these lines in my Mathematica code.

Comment: I figured as much - I suspect my answer is more appropriate for those trying to solve the corresponding problem on the RPi.

Comment: Hi Bob, if you have time, would you mind testing [this package](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/releases/tag/v0.2.0pre1) on a Raspberry Pi (2)?  I would like to make sure that it works on someone else's machine before making a full release, and this is the first time I compiled it on a Raspberry Pi.  Running the test suite on an RPi 1 is slow (half an hour). A quicker way to test is to just load the package and look at the version number: ``Get["IGraphM`"]; IGVersion[]``.  If there are no error messages shown then it worked!

Comment: @Szabolcs I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y3wub.png), which suggests that some of it is working.  I kept getting a network error when downloading [the zip](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/releases/download/v0.2.0pre1/IGraphM0.2.0pre1.zip) file but [the source](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/archive/v0.2.0pre1.zip) link worked.

Comment: @bobthechemist Thanks for trying it!  The source archive is perfect, but I think `Directory[]` should be `/home /pi/projects` and not `/home/pi/projects/IGraphM` when you issue ``<<IGraphM` `` (in the case when the package is not installed in `~/.WolframEngine/Applications`, just just loaded from the current directory).

Comment: @Szabolcs Yep, worked correctly when started from the correct directory.  Do you need/want timings for the test suite on a v2 Pi?

Comment: @bobthechemist If you have time, that would be nice.  I estimate 15 minutes or less on the RPi 2.  I am aware that the `IGBlissAutomorphismGroup` tests fail on the RPi, but that's a bug in Mathematica, not in igraph.

Comment: @Szabolcs Confirmed. Just under 900 seconds.

Comment: @bobthechemist No other failures than the one I mentioned?